# What is the difference between SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and SpringRunner

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-test

Whenever I see a blog post related to Spring testing I see either of these classes but do not understand the real difference:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Answer (score 170, accepted):

There is no difference, from the javadoc:

> SpringRunner is an alias for the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.

ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.0.RC2_to_4.3.0.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%204.3.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringRunner.html

Answer (score 41):

`@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` tells JUnit to run using Spring’s testing support. `SpringRunner` is the new name for `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`, it’s just a bit easier on the eye.

`SpringRunner` is only available on spring-test 4.3.

`SpringRunner` class extends `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

[Source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringRunner.java) of `SpringRunner` is

```
package org.springframework.test.context.junit4;

import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

public final class SpringRunner extends SpringJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public SpringRunner(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        super(clazz);
    }

}
```

Comment: this added more information to understand the detail relation between `SpringRunner` & `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.